# DateTimePicker - How to set interval of time to be 20 minutes, specific days allowed in the week and times during the day?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have been looking online to customize my date and time picker. I have tried numerous ways to get this to work and it will not work.

The date and time picker will work but in terms of using stepping, selecting a range of days, and finally a time range.

- I am looking to set the interval of time to be 20 minutes(9,20, 9.40
  etc).
- I am looking to make sure that you can only choose Monday to
  Friday
- I am looking to make sure you can only select between the
  ranges of 9-5pm.

I did notice when I used the disable feature it did disable certain days but not saturday or sunday.

Can any help me get around this problem?

This is my code

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
    
    <script>
        $(function () {
  

      
            });
    </script>



}
```

Comment: For starters, check your console for script errors and fix any syntax errors.

Comment: Hey Jasen, Sorry those syntax errors were not meant to be in this posted version. going to edit now

Comment: I have removed the code completely as I have messed around for another 2 hours and I still cannot get it working

Answer (score 0):

You can use the necessary options when initializing the datetimepicker:

1. For 20 minutes step, add the option `minuteStep: 20`
2. To disable weekends, add the option `daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]` were 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday.
3. The option to change the start and end times for a day doesn't exist in the documentation at [Bootstrap DateTimePicker](https://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/), will update the answer if I find any way.

You can use options in the following way:

`$("#date-time-element").datetimepicker({minuteStep: 20, ...});`

Comment: Siddharth Bhansali I tried implementing this and my date and time picker would not work. The code I tried was this:                                                                                                                             
        $(function () {
        $('#datepicker').datetimepicker({ minuteStep: 20, daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6] });

    });